# Plotting in r by date range

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 4000 categoric variables which are city names arranged by date. I can do a plot of the entire dataset with an overall count.
What I need to do is be able to plot aggregates of specific cities by specific date ranges. I cannot use by quarter or anything like that because the required date ranges every year are different. I need to be able to, say, select 2016/4/1 to 2016/6/23 to get a count of how many are Denver.
How can I do  this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
theme_set(theme_classic())  
df <- log %>%
  group_by(Location) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())
df

ggplot(df, aes(x = Location, y = counts)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF", stat = "identity",width = .65) +
  geom_text(aes(label = counts), vjust = -0.3) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + 
  labs(title="Locations of Library Instruction", 
       subtitle="2016-2020")
```

Comment: Add `filter()` using the date limits you said.

Comment: do you need to do it for a single date range, then @Duck answer should help, or for a list od date ranges?

Comment: To expand on Duck's comment, you can use `filter()` with `between()`, but you will need to make sure your dates are actually a date format.  `glimpse(df)` will check that.

Comment: When I use glimpse it shows $ date                         <dttm> 2016-07-20, 2016-07-20, 2016-07-19, 2016-07-18, 2016-07-14, 2016-07-14, 2016-07-1   I added a filter between as suggested but it seems not to do anything df %>%
  select(date,Location) %>%
  filter(between(date, as.date("2016-01-09"), as.date("2016-03-20")))
group_by(Location) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())

Comment: I also tried reformatting date but that had no effect # Load the libraries
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
# load data
df <- read_excel("C:/Users/12083/Desktop/instructions/datasetd.xlsx")
df$Date <-as.Date(df$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
glimpse(df)
df %>%
  select(date,Location) %>%
  filter(Date > "2016-02-04" & Date <"2016-04-18")
  #filter(between(date, as.date("2016-01-09"), as.date("2016-03-20")))
group_by(Location) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())
# Plot it
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=Location)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p